# ReactJS - how to update data for an attribute in props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of posts and for every post, there's is a button that will display a modal window with a confirmation if the user really wants to delete the respective post.

When the user confirms, data are send to backend, there's delete the respective post and back to ReactJS is returned a set of all posts. But when try to update the list of posts on the front-end, I get this error:

```
Posts.jsx:61 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this2.props.posts is not a function
```

This error is raised on this line:

```
this.props.posts(res.data);
```

**Home.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import Posts from './Posts';
import NewPost from './NewPost';
import axios from 'axios';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import LoadModal from './LoadModal';

class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

      this.state = {
        posts: [],
            loading: true
       };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/posts')
            .then(response => {
                console.log('---');
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log('---');
            this.setState({ posts: response.data, loading: false });
          });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Posts posts={this.state.posts} loading={this.state.loading} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Home
```

**Posts.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Collapse} from 'react-collapse';
import classNames from "classnames";
import Dialog from 'react-bootstrap-dialog';


class Posts extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            activeIndex: null,
            removePostBtn: 'Remove'
        }
    }

    onClick(post_id) {
        this.dialog.show({
            title: 'Remove Post - #'+post_id,
            body: 'Do you really want to remove this post?',
            actions: [
                Dialog.CancelAction(),
                Dialog.DefaultAction(
                    this.state.removePostBtn,
                    () => {
                        this.setState({ removePostBtn: 'Removing...' }, () => {
                            axios.get('/remove_post/'+post_id, { post_id: post_id })
                            .then(res => {
                                this.props.posts(res.data); // here's the error
                            })
                        })
                    },
                    'btn-danger'
                )
            ],
        })
    }

  render () {
        let content;
        const { activeIndex } = this.state;
        const Button = require('react-bootstrap').Button;

        if (this.props.loading) {
            content = 'Loading...';
        } else {
                content = this.props.posts.map((post, index) => {
                return(
                  <li key={index}>
                    <div>   
                        <span>{post.id}</span>
                        <span>{post.message}</span>
                        <Button onClick={() => this.onClick(post.id)}>Show alert</Button>
                        <Dialog ref={(el) => { this.dialog = el }} />
                    </div>
                  </li>
                )
            });

        }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Posts!</h1>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                    {content}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Posts
```

How do I properly update the `props` with `posts`?

Comment: You can't directly update any props. You need to create an update handler in whatever component is passing you `this.props.posts` that will update `this.state.posts`

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly update any props. You need to create an update handler in the parent component that will update `this.state.posts`:

```
import React from "react";
import Posts from './Posts';
import NewPost from './NewPost';
import axios from 'axios';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import LoadModal from './LoadModal';

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      loading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPosts();
  }

  getPosts = () => {
    axios.get('/posts')
    .then(response => {
      console.log('---');
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log('---');
      this.setState({ posts: response.data, loading: false });
    });
  }

  updatePosts = posts => {
    this.setState({ posts });  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Posts posts={this.state.posts} loading={this.state.loading} getPosts={this.getPosts} updatePosts={this.updatePosts} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Home

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Collapse} from 'react-collapse';
import classNames from "classnames";
import Dialog from 'react-bootstrap-dialog';


class Posts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeIndex: null,
      removePostBtn: 'Remove'
    }
  }

  onClick(post_id) {
    this.dialog.show({
      title: 'Remove Post - #'+post_id,
      body: 'Do you really want to remove this post?',
      actions: [
        Dialog.CancelAction(),
        Dialog.DefaultAction(
          this.state.removePostBtn,
          () => {
            this.setState({ removePostBtn: 'Removing...' }, () => {
            axios.get('/remove_post/'+post_id, { post_id: post_id })
            .then(res => {
              //this.props.posts(res.data); // here's the error
              // Call parent function to re-retch posts
              this.props.getPosts();
              // Or direclty pass data to update the parent state
              this.props.updatePosts(res.data);
            })
          })
       },
        'btn-danger'
        )
      ],
    })
  }

  render () {
    let content;
    const { activeIndex } = this.state;
    const Button = require('react-bootstrap').Button;

    if (this.props.loading) {
      content = 'Loading...';
    } else {
      content = this.props.posts.map((post, index) => {
          return(
      <li key={index}>
        <div>
          <span>{post.id}</span>
          <span>{post.message}</span>
          <Button onClick={() => this.onClick(post.id)}>Show alert</Button>
          <Dialog ref={(el) => { this.dialog = el }} />
        </div>
      </li>
    )
    });

    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Posts!</h1>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <ul>
              {content}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Posts
```